# Ошибка: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: close cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, gunicorn

Чат на `Flask-SocketIO + SqlAlchemy`, запушен на `gunicorn + eventlet` ошибка - `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: close cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway`

Подскажите решение проблемы, нет опыта в асинхронном програмировании, сейчас запускаю так:

```
engine = create_engine(postgresql://db_user:db_pass@localhost:5432/db_name)
session = Session(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()

class MyTab(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_tab'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True
    val = Column(String(50))
```

может есть варианты простых модулей типа `psycopg2`, которые помогут решить проблему без серьезных изменений в коде, не нашел примеров с `ORM`. Можно ли использовать `ORM` в асинхронном режиме? Или предстоит все переделать под `Core`

Лог ошибки:

```
2017-04-12 16:23:02,698 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'id_1': '1', 'param_1': 1}
Error closing cursor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/chat/virt/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context context)
  File "/var/www/chat/virt/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 450, in do_execute cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: execute cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/chat/virt/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1226, in _safe_close_cursor cursor.close()
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: close cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway
2017-04-12 16:23:02,701 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
[2017-04-12 16:23:32 +0300] [11106] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:11109)
[2017-04-12 16:23:33 +0300] [11118] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11118
Server initialized for eventlet.
```

Ранее запускал на `uwsgi + devent_uwsgi` проблем с базой небыло

Comment: Если там есть пул соединений, то соединение определённо возвращается в него раньше положенного. Во время выполнения асинхронного запроса оно (соединение) должно числиться занятым и никому не выдаваться, а возвращаться в пул только после чтения всего ответа. Виноват ли ваш код или какой-то из модулей, не знаю, не пишу на Python, выводы выше просто из сообщения об ошибке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне удалось устранить ошибку, не переписывая работу с базой с `ORM` на `Core`. Хотя для ассинхронного кода не рекомендуют объектно-реляционно отображение - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491564/how-to-make-sqlalchemy-in-tornado-to-be-async, но с этим мне еще предстоит разобраться, собственно изменен был код соединения с базой постгрес `data_models.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from contextlib import contextmanager

Base = declarative_base()
db_url = postgresql://db_user:db_pass@localhost:5432/db_name
engine = create_engine(db_url, echo=True, echo_pool=True, pool_size=50, max_overflow=0) 

def session():
    connection = engine.connect()
    db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=True, bind=engine))
    try:
        yield db_session
    except Exception as e:
        connection.rollback()
        print(e)
    finally:
        db_session.remove()
        connection.close()

class MyTab(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_tab'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True
    val = Column(String(50))
```

Обращение к базе:

```
from data_models import session, MyTab

def check_exist(uid):
    with session() as s:
        query = s.query(MyTab).filter(MyTab.id == uid).first()
        return query

def get_all():
    with session() as s:
        query = s.query(MyTab).all()
        return [dict(id=i.id, val=i.val) for i in query]
```